# Sudden shutdown - desktop computer

Tags: shutdown

I have a problem with ubuntu 12.04. It shuts down randomly, just power off. I changed the powersupply and it still happens. I have a new computer with ASUS P9X79 Pro motherboard and INTEL CPU CORE I7-3930K. The CPU is water cooled so there is no problem with high temp. Power supply has max at 750W and graphic card is not power-hungry (quadro 600). Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds distinctly like an over heating issue. Are you 100% sure you fitted all the water blocks correctly? Didn't forget the heat paste and don't have any air bubbles slowing the flow?